# how to open popup window in center

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

```
window.open('/apex/QuoteTemplate?id={!Quote.Id}',
             '_blank',
             'height=600,width=800,location= center,Window Position=center ');
```

my window get open but at top-left corner

I want that window should pop up at center

Comment: did you try 50vh and 50vw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following script in your custom button :

replace your visualforce page with **custompopup**

```
var x = screen.width/2 - 700/2;
var y = screen.height/2 - 450/2;
window.open('/apex/custompopup?id={!Quote.Id}','_blank','height=485,width=700,left='+x+',top='+y);
```